# Sorting list of names in Perl

Tags: database, perl, list, sorting, numbers

I am trying to learn Perl and I am quite new with it probably less than a week.

I want to sort a list of names(in this case fruits) and give them an ID. My script currently gives them ID but I want to sort them as well.

**Current code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %unique;

open(my $inFile, $ARGV[0]) || die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]' $!";
open(my $outFile, ">$ARGV[1]") || die "Could not find file '>$ARGV[1]' $!";

while (<$inFile>) {
        my @fields = split;

        my $fruit  = $fields[0];
        my $quantity   = $fields[1];

        my @parts = split(/[_.]/, $fruit);
        my $counter = ++$unique{$parts[1]}{$parts[2]};

        print $outFile join("\t", $fruit, $quantity, "$fruit.$counter"), "\n";
}
```

**Input:**

```
Apple   3
Apple   50
Apple   1
Orange  51
Orange  21
```

**Current Output:**

```
Apple   3   Apple.1
Apple   50  Apple.2
Apple   1   Apple.3
Orange  51  Orange.1
Orange  21  Orange.2
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
Apple   1   Apple.1
Apple   3   Apple.2
Apple   50  Apple.3
Orange  21  Orange.1
Orange  51  Orange.2
```

**or**

```
Apple   3   Apple.2
Apple   50  Apple.3
Apple   1   Apple.1
Orange  51  Orange.2
Orange  21  Orange.1
```

Thanks

***UPDATE:***

**New Input:**

```
Apple   3   1
Apple   50  2
Apple   1   3
Orange  51  3
Orange  21  5
```

**Wanted Output**

```
Apple   1   3   Apple.1
Apple   3   1   Apple.2
Apple   50  2   Apple.3
Orange  21  5   Orange.1
Orange  51  3   Orange.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Read in the data
my @data;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   push @data, [ split(/\t/, $_, -1) ];
}

# Sort it
@data = sort {
   $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]   # By name
      ||
   $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]   # By quantity
} @data;

# Generate the ids and output the data.
my %counts;
for my $row (@data) {
   my $id = join('.', $row->[0], ++$counts{ $row->[0] });
   push @$row, $id;
   print(join("\t", @$row), "\n");
}
```

Comment: I am now trying to sort out a list with more columns, it seems like I can only sort the quantity and the ID. I also want to change the value of my added column. I would be really thankful to you if you can help me or give me tips on this one.

Comment: Did you even add the extra fields to the array? Updated.

Comment: Yes I have, if I want to sort the list by the 3rd column instead of the 2nd coloumn, do I need to add another operator in the data subroutine

Comment: Yes, if you want to have it sort in a different order, you will have to change the callback that controls the order (the curlies after `sort`).

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I understand how it works now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses a couple of CPAN modules ([`Sort::Key::Multi`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Multi) and [`DDP`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer)) for fun.

```
#!perl -l
use Sort::Key::Multi 'sii_keysort' ;

my @mungeddata = sii_keysort { chomp ; split /\s+/ , $_ }  <DATA> ;

use DDP;
p @mungeddata ;

__DATA__
Apple    3    1
Apple    50   2
Apple    1    3
Orange   51   3
Orange   21   5
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [0] "Apple    1    3",
    [1] "Apple    3    1",
    [2] "Apple    50   2",
    [3] "Orange   21   5",
    [4] "Orange   51   3"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Read in the data
my @data;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   push @data, [ split(/\t/, $_, -1) ];
}

# Sort it
@data = sort {
   $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]   # By name
      ||
   $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]   # By quantity
} @data;

# Generate the ids and output the data.
my %counts;
for my $row (@data) {
   my $id = join('.', $row->[0], ++$counts{ $row->[0] });
   push @$row, $id;
   print(join("\t", @$row), "\n");
}
```